# PHP Video Stream Seekbar Unusable in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, video, seekbar

This is somewhat related to my other PHP video streaming post, but this time the issue is that the seekbar for the videos do not work in Chrome.

I have found several different posts about it here at Stack Overflow, but none of them have resolved the issue. I would link all of them, but I can't seem to find the same posts I found yesterday.

I am going to list two versions of the PHP code. I should also point out what exactly I'm doing before the PHP loads the video data. On an HTML page, I have a `<video>` tag without `<source>` tags. I use Javascript to make an AJAX call to a PHP file that has the source tags. The source tags themselves don't contain direct links to the video source files. Instead, they reference yet another PHP file that loads the data.

Top level HTML For Video. Super simple.

```
<video id="showvideo" height="540" width="864" controls></video>
```

Now for the AJAX call

```
function showVideo() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("showvideo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
    }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "/firstphpfile.php", true);

    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

The Javascript function loads when the page loads.

Here's the contents of firstphpfile.php

```
<?php

echo "

<source src=\"http://example.com/video1.php?type=stuff.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\">

<source src=\"http://example.com/video2.php?type=stuff.ogv\" type=\"video/ogg\">
";
?>
```

Again, not a big deal. Now I am going to post a couple different versions of the video1.php file that actually grabs the file resource.

Version 1:

```
<?php

$file = video.mp4;



$filesize = filesize($file);

$offset = 0;
$length = $filesize;

if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) ) {
// if the HTTP_RANGE header is set we're dealing with partial content

$partialContent = true;

// find the requested range
// this might be too simplistic, apparently the client can request
// multiple ranges, which can become pretty complex, so ignore it for now
preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);

$offset = intval($matches[1]);
$length = intval($matches[2]) - $offset;
} else {
$partialContent = false;
}

$file = fopen($file, 'r');

// seek to the requested offset, this is 0 if it's not a partial conten request
fseek($file, $offset);

$data = fread($file, $length);

fclose($file);

if ( $partialContent ) {
// output the right headers for partial content

header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');

header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + $length) . '/' . $filesize);
}

// output the regular HTTP headers
header("Content-Type:video/mp4");
header('Content-Length: $filesize');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

// don't forget to send the data too
print($data);



?>
```

Version 2 (I like this one better for what it does in Firefox, but still no dice in Chrome)

```
<?php

$file = video.mp4;


$mime = "video/mp4"; // The MIME type of the file, this should be replaced with your own.
$size = filesize($file); // The size of the file

// Send the content type header
header('Content-type: ' . $mime);

// Check if it's a HTTP range request
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){
// Parse the range header to get the byte offset
$ranges = array_map(
    'intval', // Parse the parts into integer
    explode(
        '-', // The range separator
        substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 6) // Skip the `bytes=` part of the header
    )
);

// If the last range param is empty, it means the EOF (End of File)
if(!$ranges[1]){
    $ranges[1] = $size - 1;
}

// Send the appropriate headers
header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . ($ranges[1] - $ranges[0])); // The size of the range

// Send the ranges we offered
header(
    sprintf(
        'Content-Range: bytes %d-%d/%d', // The header format
        $ranges[0], // The start range
        $ranges[1], // The end range
        $size // Total size of the file
    )
);

// It's time to output the file
$f = fopen($file, 'rb'); // Open the file in binary mode
$chunkSize = 8192; // The size of each chunk to output

// Seek to the requested start range
fseek($f, $ranges[0]);

// Start outputting the data
while(true){
    // Check if we have outputted all the data requested
    if(ftell($f) >= $ranges[1]){
        break;
    }

    // Output the data
    echo fread($f, $chunkSize);

    // Flush the buffer immediately
    @ob_flush();
    flush();
    }
}
else {
// It's not a range request, output the file anyway
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

// Read the file
@readfile($file);

// and flush the buffer
@ob_flush();
flush();
}


?>
```

So, while both play the video without problems, only the Firefox version will let me do any kind of seeking. The second version makes it so you can only seek backwards, which I prefer.

There was another version I tried, but I had already deleted the code before writing this and haven't found it again.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong and no solutions I have found solved the issue of allowing the Chrome version of the video to seek.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally got it to work. I decided to not load in the php files with javascript.

Also, I got rid of the mime type variable and just set the header properly. I found that using a variable for the mime type cause my browsers to load the wrong mime type for the content type header thus causing the video resource to fail.